# Can this be done in one line?

Tags: perl

I am extracting the MAC address like so

```
my @tmp = split / /, "domain (123.123.123.123) at 00:11:22:33:44:55 [ether] on eth0";
my $vip = $tmp[3];
```

but can it be done without using a temporary variable?

Comment: If there is any possibility of leading whitespace, use `split ' '`.

Comment: `split ' '` will also handle tabs, and will treat consecutive whitespace characters as one.

Comment: @ikegami Which is correct behaviour in this case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it can:

```
my $vip = (split / /, "domain (123.123.123.123) at 00:11:22:33:44:55 [ether] on eth0")[3];
```

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting, fyi, the temporary values are still created. They're just not assigned to an array.

Comment: It notified me of your message, but I'm not the one who downvoted you. I guess it's because I left a comment?

Answer (score 13):

[Yes it can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895669/conversion-of-list-context-result-to-array-in-one-line-in-perl/7895949#7895949)

```
my (undef, undef, undef, $vip) = split / /, "...";
```

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend this approach, which looks for a "proper" MAC address at word boundaries in the haystack. If the MAC address moves in the string, it will still work, and if `$vip` is not defined following this statement, no MAC address was found. Let me know if I can clarify anything.

```
my ($vip) = "..." =~ /\b((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}[:-]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2})\b/;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `grep`. This will grab the first field that matches the regex. Note that unless you specifically want multiple spaces to result in empty fields, you should use `' '`, not `/ /`.

```
my ($vip) = grep /^[0-9:]+$/, split ' ', "...";
```

Comment: Instead of using grep and split in this situation, it would probably be better to simply capture the first match: `my ($vip) = "..." =~ /\b((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}[:-]){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2})\b/`

Comment: Nice smiley in that regex. =) I considered a regex, but I found it to be rather complex, and I prefer two simple filters (split + grep) to one complex. Complex regexes can be hard to maintain, and something you missed can bring the whole thing down.

Comment: Fair enough, but your regex won't match most MAC addresses (you forgot hex digits A-F), and it's a little too permissive. For example, it would match "0" and "0:" and "00000:::::". After some improvements, you would end up with a split, a grep, AND a complex regex. :-]

Comment: @mwp If those characters are possible in MAC addresses, then my solution is probably not suitable, and you are right that I might as well write a regex. I am going to delete my answer. You should post your regex as an answer, rather than a comment, though.

Comment: Oh, don't delete it. TMTOWTDI. I will, however, take your advice. :-)

Comment: @mwp Well, if it were to match a proper MAC address with all those characters `[0-9A-Fa-f:-]` then I *do* need a stricter regex. But I see I have two upvotes now, so perhaps I'll just leave the answer. Also: Good for you. +1 to you.