# How do I extract an element of a split array without a intermediate variable in Perl?

Tags: perl

Given the string `Wibble eq wobble myhost.example.com` I would like to be able to extract the last element.

My current effort is:

```
my @parts = split( /\s+/, "Wibble eq wobble myhost.example.com");
my $host = $parts[-1];
print "$host\n";
```

How do I do this with out the intermediate `@parts` array?

Comment: for that particular case, you can just use a regular expression to extract the last field: `my ($host) = ($str =~ /(\S+)$/)`

Comment: @salva -  super, put that as an answer and you get a upvote :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can this be done in one line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997616/can-this-be-done-in-one-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
my $host = (split( /\s+/, "Wibble eq wobble myhost.example.com"))[-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (to the [answer already given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11047075/170194)), try that:

```
my $host = pop [split /\s+/, "Wibble eq wobble myhost.example.com"];
```

or, if you dont like split:

```
my $host = pop [qw "Wibble eq wobble myhost.example.com"];
```

or, more perlish:

```
my $host = (qw "Wibble eq wobble myhost.example.com")[-1];
```

rbo