# how to get just one scalar from perl split command

Tags: perl

I use to know how to do this.  I just want to grab a substring out a larger string and assign it to scalar.  So here is the Perl script I have hacked up ...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

my $thing = "thing1 thing2 thing3 thing4 thing5 thing6 thing7 thing8";
my $thing4 = ${@{split (/ /, $thing)}[3]};
print "thing4 is $thing4\n";
```

... the output I get is this ...

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in split at ./perlex.pl line 6.
Can't use string ("0") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ./perlex.pl line 6.
```

... I was hoping that the output would be ...

```
thing4 is thing4
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't reproduce that exact error, what version of perl are you using?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7997616

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You greatly overengineered the `split` line.  It should just be:

```
my $thing4 = (split / /, $_)[3];
```

Answer (score 4):

This expression

```
${@{split (/ /, $_)}[3]}
```

means:

- split the `$_` variable at all spaces. This happens in scalar context, so it evaluates to the number of fields, e.g. `5`
- The `@{ ... }` treats the inner expression as an array reference and dereferences it as an array, e.g. `@5`.
- The `@{ ... }[3]` picks the fourth element of that array, with quite questionable syntax. E.g. `@5[3]` which might be `"foo"`, but likely is `undef`.
- The `${ ... }` treats that as a scalar reference, and dereferences it. E.g. `${foo}`

The result: mayhem. You actually wanted:

```
my $some_thing = (split)[3];
```